# Is there any other method to fix this problem?

Tags: php, pdo

When I start the native PHP server in console mode I cannot connect to the database

I have this error message.

`Could not find driver`

But when I do not start the native server the connection is established very well.
I do not understand anything please need help.

Comment: "_it is well activated in the PHP.ini file_" Is it the correct `php.ini` file? `phpinfo()` should show which one the webserver uses. There's also another `php.ini` for CLI

Comment: Hi! Maybe try checking if multiple `.ini` files. PHP might be using a different one. You can find this by going to the first section of the `phpinfo()`! (Check the value of: `Loaded Configuration File` This will tell you which file PHP is looking at!

Comment: the file **php.ini** is the one located in the php7.3.1 folder the one in the directory  c: / wam64 / bin / php / php7.3.1 / php.ini

Comment: did you restart your wamp services ?

Comment: I tried. And it was rather the PHP.ini file from the apache directory. Even in that file the extension is enabled so I don't believe the problem is there.

Comment: I have restarted the services several times.

Comment: I found a clue about me problem. Actually the extension is installed.

There is a small problem.  When I do:

php -S localhost: 7000 In command line 
And in the browser I typed: ```localhost: 7000``` Result 

**Could not find driver**


But when I type
```localhost/project/index.php```
Result

**Connection establish**

In this case, how do we do it?